# how to set labels in inline assembly?

Tags: visual-c++, inline-assembly

how in c++ visual can i set labels for when i need to use inline assembly, so it would look like something like this for example...

```
__asm
{
    PUSH EAX
    PUSH VAR1
    MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[VAR2]
    CALL DWORD PTR DS:[VAR3]
    JMP VAR4
}
```

where the `VAR` varables link to a value or address?

i have tried the following

```
DWORD   VAR2 = 0x991770;    //0x991770 is the location of the function

__asm
{
    ..code
    MOV ECX,DWORD PTR DS:[VAR2]
    ..code
}
```

but then the app crashes, how is this done?

Comment: If you hard-code the address and it can change from run to run (by the PE loader), then there's nothing strange in your program crashing. How about `DWORD VAR2 = (DWORD)&SomeFunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `offset variableName` to access variables from inline assembly. See reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8b57x4b%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Example:

```
char format[] = "%s %s\n";
char hello[] = "Hello";
char world[] = "world";
int main( void )
{
   __asm
   {
      mov  eax, offset world
      push eax
      mov  eax, offset hello
      push eax
      mov  eax, offset format
      push eax
      call printf
      //clean up the stack so that main can exit cleanly
      //use the unused register ebx to do the cleanup
      pop  ebx
      pop  ebx
      pop  ebx
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C variable names are visible in inline assembly. So if you need data access, just write the var name:

```
int var2 = 3;
__asm
{
    mov ecx, var2
```

That will compile to the appropriate memory access statement.

For code labels - you just declare them, like in real assembly:

```
Label1:
    mov ecx, 0
    jmp Label1
```

External functions are seen as labels, too. Name mangling applies, though.

If you need the numeric value of the current IP as a general purpose register, there's no direct command, but a very simple workaround is available:

```
    call Next
Next:
    pop eax ; eax now is the value of IP at the current point
```

Oh, and forget about the `ds:` stuff. You're in Flatland now - check your segment registers at the door.